# Bring an activity to front in android Broadcast Reciever

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to launch an activity , when i got an incoming call for my android mobile. For that, in ringing state, i started an activity and sets some flags for bring this activity to front. Here is the Code:

```
       Intent intent2open = new Intent(ctx,  Main.class);
    intent2open.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP); 
    intent2open.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent2open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent2open.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent2open.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
        intent2open.putExtra(name, value);
    startActivity(intent2open);
```

By using above code, i didnt get my required output, some cases app will be launched when i accepted or rejected my call.
In some other cases,it will be launched when the state in ringing. I am unable to addressed this issue.. How can i bring my activity to front.

Thanks in advance,
Lokesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your activity in manifest and set your flags as:

```
intent2open.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

**at least it works well for me in my project*

---

**Update**

Increase of priority in manifest for your broadcast's intent-filter may also help you in this case:

```
<!-- Higher numbers have a higher priority -->
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
```

Comment: if there's also another activity which is supposed to appear (in your case call-activity) then its uncertain to know which appears first as its matter of who receives broadcast first - depending upon their priority. See my updated answer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority

Comment: apart from your code lines, i changed my class launching mode to "singleInstance".