# How can move my application on foreground?

Tags: android, multithreading

When a certain event occurs, the thread of my application sends the message to the activity. All is well while the application is active. But if the application is minimized, then activity can not get a message from the thread. How do I move my application to the forefront if an event occurs in the thread?

I tried to use BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ReadCardReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context mContext;
public static final String ACTION = "com.test.action.ACTION";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION)) {

      Intent activivtyIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
        activivtyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(activivtyIntent);


    }
}
```

}

but if I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, then created a new activity, but I need to open an existing one. If I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, then I have exception:

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I just need to bring my application to the forefront. How can i do this?

**ADD1**: I have an exception, if I set android:launchMode="singleTop" :

```
08-08 17:44:25.350 668-668/com.test W/System.err: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-08 17:44:25.360 668-668/com.test W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1123)
08-08 17:44:25.360 668-668/com.test W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1110)
08-08 17:44:25.370 668-668/com.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:311)
08-08 17:44:25.370 668-668/com.test W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:311)
08-08 17:44:25.370 668-668/com.test W/System.err:     at com.test.ReadCardReciver.onReceive(ReadCardReciver.java:23)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bring an activity to front in android Broadcast Reciever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873560/bring-an-activity-to-front-in-android-broadcast-reciever)

Comment: No, please see ADD1

Comment: Yes, please see the accepted answer of the possible duplicate

Comment: This code creates a new activity, but I need to open an existing one.

Comment: when the new instance is created, does it receive a Bundle with savedInstanceState?

Comment: No, for what I need to do this? Activity not destroyed, but paused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151461/discussion-between-andrew-efremov-and-lelloman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the particular activity launch mode to the single top in the manifest.

```
android:launchMode = "singleTop"
```

And start an activity like as usual

```
    Intent activivtyIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
    |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    context.startActivity(activivtyIntent);
```

It will bring the existing alive activity instead of creating a new one.

You can get more idea about launch mode here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: I get an exception, 08-08 17:44:25.350 668-668/by.mtbank.mpos W/System.err: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: This code creates a new activity, but I need to open an existing one.